# Desarrollar aplicación móvil que cree un registro y automáticamente se actualiza una aplicación web sin tener que recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, nodejs, rest

Necesito desarrollar una aplicación para Android donde el usuario cree un producto, este se guarde en la base de datos y que de forma asíncrona se muestre en la aplicación web, sin tener que recargar la pagina con cada nuevo registro.
cesito desarrollar una aplicación para Android donde el usuario cree un producto, este se guarde en la base de datos y que de forma asíncrona se muestre en la aplicación web, sin tener que recargar la pagina con cada nuevo registro.

1.¿Esto seria crear una API REST o únicamente con AJAX es posible?

2.¿Que herramientas necesito para eso?, pensaba emplear MySQL, Exprees, Angular.js y Node.js.

Me podrían orientar con un ejemplo (diagrama) de como sería la arquitectura del sistema.

Comment: Te entiendo bien que pides la arquitectura para lo describes en forma abstracta en un diagrama? Estas pensando en UML?

Comment: Podrías intentar con Firebase para tu backend, por si tu experiencia es mayor con Android que con creación de APIs Rest.

Comment: Un diagrama sencillo, no necesariamente UML, solamente para tener una idea de como es el flujo de datos y así entender como implementar las tecnologías